# La « bordée » de neige ?

Tags: sens, étymologie, québec, origine-ou-raison, régionalismes

La [*bordée*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bord%C3%A9e) pour la *grosse quantité de* est un régionalisme, particulièrement une *(grosse) bordée de neige* au Canada (et encore davantage au [Québec](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/grand-montreal/201902/13/01-5214574-au-moins-une-semaine-pour-ramasser-la-neige-a-montreal.php)...) pour la « chute très importante de neige » ([Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bord%C3%A9e/10226/locution?q=bord%C3%A9e#169054) ; et non pas quand la [neige](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/neiger) [a neigé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soir_d%27hiver) quelques « [plumes folles](https://books.google.com/books?id=mp-kbt4dJxoC&lpg=PP1&dq=Le%20Survenant%2C1945&pg=PA87#v=snippet&q=plumes%20folles&f=false) »)...

[image]
<sup><sup>Source : [Ville de Montréal](http://ville.montreal.qc.ca/deneigement/)</sup></sup>

- Peut-on en préciser l'étymologie et l'origine et dire si le sens
  dérive d'une notion de densité ou de quantité ou autrement ?
- Incidemment conçoit-on l'emploi au pluriel (chez Duhamel, par exemple : « Quelques bordées de grêlons » au TLFi) différemment ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le [TLFI](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bord%C3%A9e) donne le sens de « grosse quantité de … » spécifiquement avec la mention « attaque verbale ». Je crois que cela correspond à l'usage en France, et en tout cas cela correspond à mon usage. Je m'attends plus à « recevoir une bordée d'injures » qu'à « recevoir une bordée de compliments », même si le second n'est pas forcément exclu. Le TLFI donne des exemples « bordée d'injures », « bordée de jurons », « bordée de boutades », « bordée de bêtises » tirés d'auteurs qui viennent de diverses régions de France.

Pour l'utilisation météorologique, le TLFI encore cite « bordée de grêlons » chez [Georges Duhamel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georges_Duhamel) qui était Parisien. Le [GDT](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8356664) signale

> Le terme bordée, au sens de « grande quantité », notamment dans les expressions bordée de pluie et bordée de grêle, existait déjà dans le parler de la [Saintonge (France)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saintonge).

C'est effectivement plus régional que la « bordée d'injure ». Je n'aurais pas spontanément parlé de bordée de pluie, mais l'expression se comprend de façon transparente.

Pour ce qui est de l'étymologie, en fait, le TLFI donne la réponse. Au départ, le mot *bordée* est un terme de marine, avec plusieurs sens différents. En particulier, il désigne la partie de l'équipage qui est affectée à un côté d'un bateau. Ensuite il désigne l'ensemble des canons situés sur un côté d'un bateau, puis il prend le sens d'un tir simultané des canons situés sur un côté d'un bateau. Une *bordée*, c'est donc un tir simultané de plusieurs projectiles. On comprend ainsi les deux sens figurés courants, où les boulets de canon sont remplacés par des mots ou par des gouttes d'eau, flocons de neige ou grêlons. Avec dans tous les cas une connotation agressive, même si je pense qu'elle a tendance à s'atténuer pour simplement signaler une grosse quantité.

Comment: Le propos au GDT est comme au [GPFC](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf). Je ne suis pas familier avec aucun autre emploi qu'avec la neige, et j'ai de la difficulté à l'associer à des choses qui ne créent pas une accumulation, on dirait que je le perçois comme une substantivation de « [débordée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9bord%C3%A9e) » pour ainsi dire (truc qui dépasse visiblement le bord...)... c'est peut-être ça qui m'amenait à parler de densité, ou l'idée de tir groupé. Au final tous les trucs viennent de la barque au Qc..